# Design architecture for simple multiple process in C?

Tags: c, architecture, multiple-processes

I need an advice about which design architecture for simple multiple process in c language I should use.

It is supposed to be a simple program that creates a number of child process and executes, sleeps and after exit to let other child processes work.

Which one you would prefer to choose as a architecture?

- Data Flow -> Batch Sequential
- Call and Return -> Main program/sub program or Classical Object
- Interacting Process -> Communicating Process or Distrubuted
- Data-Centered Repository -> Client server etc

Comment: What have you considered so far? Can you be more specific about the program's requirements?

Comment: requirements are actually not complex. Main program is suppose to create a number of child. Action of child process are creation execution, sleep and exit. Every action of children must be written in a shared log file. Those are the only requirements that program has